# How can i solve print(""" [some <br>] """) invalid syntax problem

Tags: python, printing

When I'm running the following code:

```
print ("""Russian Lounge Pls Select Your Lang. etc(tr,en,ru)""")
lang = input(print "Please Select Your Lang :")
```

---

is generated a error. How I can solve it ?

```
BurNet@Casper MINGW64 ~/Desktop/RUlounge
$ python client.py
  File "client.py", line 28
    '''
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Remove the `print` in `input(print "Please Select Your Lang :")`.

Comment: Can you specify which version of python you are using? By the way print is don't needed and possibly generates the syntax error. However it seems that something goes wrong the first print, if you can add all the code so we can understand better the problem and help you at the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message before the input prompt, just pass the string to `input()`, no need to use `print` there.

```
print("Russian Lounge Pls Select Your Lang. etc(tr,en,ru)")
lang = input("Please Select Your Lang: ")
print(lang)
```

Note: this assumes you are using `Python 3.x`, where the `print` statement uses parenthesis.